# How do I ensure correctness when using find_in_batches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, batch-processing

current my application have stat needs and I

make up a background job using rufus-scheduler and runs at 3:00

to batch process these records into CacheStat table. It's just like

any normal application's Weekly/Monthly Stat needs.

And I found out using find_each(say using User.find_each to iterate
all users), which invokes find_in_batches, I checkout the source code
of rails,

```
   while records.any?
    records_size = records.size
    primary_key_offset = records.last.id

    yield records

    break if records_size < batch_size

    if primary_key_offset
      records = relation.where(table[primary_key].gt(primary_key_offset)).to_a
    else
      raise "Primary key not included in the custom select clause"
    end
  end
```

which the implentation is by comparing the primary-key,
my concern is the cocurrency,while I processing the batch,
whatif some records be inserted in-between?
does anybody have this kind of problem?

While I think, this code implementation may be be problemic,

because new records will always have larger PK and later in the

end will be find.

So this is what this kind of needs be implemented? If I want to

implement a batch stat processing by myself(without rails), then I

need to ensure have an integer primary key and using these fields to

compare(better not to use other kind of fields)?

(I was thinking of this because I'm kind of in the middle of switching

from mysql to mongo, so maybe later I need to implement this kind of

functionality by myself).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can ensure correctness here by enforcing [transactional isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), e.g.

```
User.transaction do
  User.find_each do |user|
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it really good to put so large things in a transaction, most stats based calculation will iterate all tables which will have more than 1 million documents, will transaction really good? I original using find_each rather than User.all(which loads all into memory) is memory/cpu usage concern.